# VNC unattended Server (No user Interaction)

Tags: vnc, remote-access

I worked on a proof on concept a while ago.... whereby I managed to get VNC going in full "unattended" mode...

I.e. The VNC Server dials into the viewer... which is running in Listening mode. The same concept of how single click works, but without the user interaction.

I cant seem to locate my source files for this concept I worked on... although I have found my shortcut that worked on the Viewer side to listen.

```
"C:\Program Files\UltraVNC\vncviewer.exe" -listen 5007 /noauto /256colors
```

I can not however remember/locate my demo of what the server is doing.... how to configure it. If I remember correctly, the server was also started with command line params that "dialed" into a remote IP/port, that the viewer is listening on.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are thinking of the server-side command [vncconnect](http://www.tightvnc.com/vncconnect.1.php).

Comment: Thanks, that seems like it will work. I did however find what I was looking for now on the ultra vnc side. Your suggestion applies to RealVNC which is slightly different, although your suggestion surely should do the job. Thanks

Comment: On the viewer side create a shortcut with -listen <viewer port>
on the server, create a shortcut with "C:\Program Files\UltraVNC\winvnc.exe" -connect <viewer ip>::<viewer port>

Comment: Perhaps mention the server is also Windows and/or tag the question with 'windows'?